# ¿Cómo realizar función ".replace()" en python?

Tags: python, bucle-for, replace

Me pregunto cómo realizar este programa sin el **.replace()**. Imagino que hay que utilizar un **for**, pero no sé muy bien como cambiar ese programa para que realice la misma acción sin utilizar la función **.replace()**.

```
str = "Esto es un ejemplo"
str.replace("e","o")
print (str)

//Output: Este es un ejemple
```

Gracias a tod@s por adelantado.

Comment: Hola, se puede hacer de forma simple con ciclos `for`, condicionales y concatenado de cadenas o usando una lista,  `list.append` y `str.join`. Para un solo carácter (`str.replace` puede reemplazar también subcadenas) basta un ciclo `for` y un condicional. ¿has intentado algo para implementarla? La pregunta es confusa en el sentido de que el código que muestras tampoco es válido, la salida que muestras no es la de `str.replace` porque no actúa in-place, retorna una nueva cadena, por lo que `print(str)` imprime la cadena original, supongo que te falta una asignación: `str = str.replace("e","o")`

Comment: si, me he dado cuenta del fallo, quedaría así str = "Esto es un ejemplo"
str.replace("e","o")
print (str

Comment: La solución con str.replace() me parece sencilla, pero si estás interesado en hacer algo con un ciclo `for` considera que el string lo puedes acceder como una lista `string[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que iterar por todas las letras de la cadena, y reemplazar con la letra por la cual deseas. En este caso con un `for` y un `if` podrías hacerlo.

```
palabra = "Esto es un ejemplo"
palabra_reemplazada = ""
for letra in palabra:
    if letra=="o":
        letra="e"
    palabra_reemplazada += letra
print(palabra_reemplazada)
```

Resultado:

```
Este es un ejemple
```

No estoy muy seguro por que quieres hacerlo por un `for()`, si `replace()` ya esta optimizada para ese uso. Si apenas estas aprendiendo a programar te recomiendo esta pagina de ejercicios: [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/).